# How to use custom payload in dialogflow to create quick replies on web integration

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am currently trying to add functionality to my chatbot by allowing it to have quick replies (buttons for the user to click on) when certain questions are raised by the user. However, the implementation on web is not as straightforward as FB messenger/telegram where quick replies can just be keyed in.

After some research it seems like using the custom payload option when selecting a response on dialogflow seems to be the only viable option but I have no idea on the type of code/ format that should be input.

Comment: Did you find the correct format ?